# Titanium Studio - FLEXIBLE_SPACE emulation in Android

Tags: android, titanium

I'm having some trouble trying to emulate `Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE` and wondered if there's any suggestions (or native functionality I haven't noticed). At the moment I have a temporary work-around to emulate a toolbar, where if there is one item then it will be centred, if two then the first will be on the left and the second on the right, and if more than three then each item which isn't the first or the last is assigned to a specific slot in the view (the width of the slot depending on the number of items). In the below example `items` is an array of `Ti.UI.Button` objects and `view` is a `Ti.Ui.View` object. The `systemButton` (when on Android) is a string which corresponds to its equivalent iOS 'constant'.

```
// Iterate over each item
for (var i in items)
{

    // Continue if a flexible space
    if ('FLEXIBLE_SPACE' === items[i].systemButton)
    {
        continue
    }

    // If there is more than one item
    if (1 !== items.length)
    {

        // Get the key
        var key = parseInt(i, 10)

        // Set the position
        switch (true)
        {

            // First
            case (0 === key):
                items[i].left = 0
                break

            // Last
            case (items.length - 1 === key):
                items[i].right = 0
                break

            // Otherwise if there are more than 3 items
            case (3 < items.length):

                // Get the slot width
                var slot = 100 / items.length

                // If a left position
                if (key < items.length / 2)
                {
                    items[i].left = (slot * key) + '%'
                }

                // Otherwise
                else
                {
                    items[i].right = (slot * (items.length - key - 1)) + '%'
                }

                // Break
                break

        }

    }

    // Add the item to the view
    view.add(items[i])

}
```

This works acceptably (not perfectly) in certain cases, but not always when flexible spaces are used as, by definition, they do not fit into the fixed width slots I've assigned.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

I should mention that I'm looking for a dynamic solution; I know that I can explicitly define the left and right positions in each individual case but I'd rather (if possible) be able to pass an array of `Ti.UI.Button` objects to a function and have it return a `Ti.Ui.View` object as a pseudo-toolbar with the buttons positioned according to the presence of flexible spaces.

Comment: Android doesn't support Toolbar. So you can use a view instead of toolbar in android. That would be better

Comment: I am using a view. I'm just wondering if there's a way to emulate FLEXIBLE_SPACE.

Comment: Try to adjust the left, right values of the items with respect to their number

Comment: That's what I have done above, but again, it doesn't work well with flexible spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some playing around I think I've come up with a solution. It does require having to explicitly define the width of the toolbar and each item, but that's not much of an issue. It works by subtracting the width of each non-flexible space from the toolbar width and then dividing what's left by the number of flexible spaces gives the width of each flexible space. Each item is then iterated over and added to the toolbar except with flexible spaces which are switched with an empty view with a width equal to the flexible space width. Below is the code in action:

```
// Create a toolbar
function createToolbar(data)
{

    // Create the toolbar
    var toolbar = Ti.UI.createView(data)

    // Set the height
    toolbar.height = 44

    // Set the layout
    toolbar.layout = 'horizontal'

    // If there are items
    if (undefined !== toolbar.items)
    {

        // The width
        var width = toolbar.width

        // The number of flexible spaces
        var spaces = 0

        // Iterate over each item
        for (var i in toolbar.items)
        {

            // If not a flexible space then subtract the item width from the total width
            if ('FLEXIBLE_SPACE' !== toolbar.items[i].systemButton)
            {
                width -= toolbar.items[i].width
            }

            // Otherwise increment the number of flexible spaces
            else
            {
                ++spaces
            }

        }

        // Iterate over each item
        for (var i in toolbar.items)
        {

            // If the item is a flexible space
            if ('FLEXIBLE_SPACE' === toolbar.items[i].systemButton)
            {

                // Create the flexible space
                var space = Ti.UI.createView(
                {
                    width: width / spaces
                }
                )

                // Add the space to the toolbar
                toolbar.add(space)

            }

            // Otherwise add the item to the toolbar
            else
            {
                toolbar.add(toolbar.items[i])
            }

        }

    }

    // Return the toolbar
    return toolbar

}
```